# Getting user country from googleapis login

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I am planning to implement google sign in on my website, now the current information i can get from the following endpoint:-

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=
```

Is

```
{
  "iss": "accounts.google.com",
  "azp": "313174994260-fba5atonf6j2bei2.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "aud": "313174994260-fba5atonf6j2bei2.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "sub": "116071052965",
  "email": "email@gmail.com",
  "email_verified": "true",
  "at_hash": "abhO2Chk4tDEd",
  "name": "Joe Doe",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-5_-NHC44/AA/ju8H1MKQF8vMu541xDO8Q/s96-c/photo.jpg",
  "given_name": "Joe",
  "family_name": "Doe",
  "locale": "en-GB",
  "iat": "1612148807",
  "exp": "1612152407",
  "jti": "f338940edea1998fc4b2606c1fd9c43333941a63",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "03b2d22c2fecf873ed19e5b8cf704afb7e2ed4be",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

How can i get the user country ?

Comment: Is it reaĺly possible to detect user country with this api?

Comment: @MohammadKamrulHasan i am not sure, that why i asked question, we may be able to get user country from google user profile, same as how we get user profile photo and other